# git submodule breaks repo, cloning the submodule directly works

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules, git-clone, bitbucket-server

I've found an issue in which I'm using this command:

`git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@someurl:9999/someproject/repoX.git`

git clones the repo successfully if I dont pass git clone any flags, but gives me this error when I use --recurse-submodules and git attempts to clone the single submodule:

```
git@someurl: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@someurl:9999/someproject/submodule_repo.git' into submodule path 'C:/someproject/submodule_repo' failed
```

The obvious answer is that my permissions are bad, but I can clone the submodule repo directly without issue..
This command succeeds:
`git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@someurl:9999/someproject/submodule_repo.git`

what gives git?

Comment: Do you have two different Git installations? The automatic submodule clone is acting like it's using a different `git clone` command, ginve that your own manual run worked. That's particularly odd since you *can* install more than one Git version and if you do, each one is supposed to carefully run itself and not the other Git version.